# React how to deal with accessing variable deep within an object, if it doesnt always exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I have one page for creating a company, and one for editing its details.

they are identical except for the fact that one will start empty and the other will pre-populate with details if they exist.

I am trying to use the same component here, and have a variable for `isEditing = true/false`

my company obj looks like this

```
address: {address: "asdf", city: "asdf", country: "asdf", postal: "asdf"}
company_id: 44
contact: {firstName: "asdf", lastName: "asdf", personalEmail: "asdf", phone1: "asdf", phone2: "asdf", …}
email: "asdf"
name: "my company"
```

I had no problems before, but when I decided to group the address/contact fields into an obj,   it started crashing.

When assigning the value to my city field for example I do
`value = {companyDetails.address.city}`

When I create a company the state
`companyDetails = {}`

This leads to an error `cannot access .city of undefined because companyDetails.address does not exist etc.`

I solved this on the editing company page with a loading state to wait for company.address to exist, but that doesn't work on the create page because it will never exist?

I have currently solved this on the create page by setting the initial state of

```
commanyDetails = {
    name:"",
    email:"",
    address: {},
    contact: {},
    notes:""
}
```

instead of just `companyDetails={}`, is this the best way to handle it?  doesn't really feel like it to me so here I am..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can guard against any of the steps in a nested chain of property accesses crashing your program by using the `&&` operator, like so:

```
companyDetails && companyDetails.address && companyDetails.address.city
```

This will return `undefined` or `null` if any of the steps encountered along the way are, rather than crashing with an error: see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND), particularly [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#Short-circuit_evaluation) section.

And the language specification now includes a [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator to make this less verbose, particularly for long chains:

```
companyDetails?.address?.city
```

but please note that the browser support for this is not particularly good yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use optional chaining to prevent this issue. Optional chaining is meant to make. your life easier when accessing deep nested objects :

```
value = companyDetails?.address?.city
```

If you don't want to use those (not supported by old browsers) you can simply do multiple checks like this :

```
value = (companyDetails && companyDetails.address && companyDetails.address.city) || ''
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

Answer (score 1):

The other answers provided are very much on point. But if you wanted something simple, the utility library `lodash` has a method for this:

> `_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])`

```
 
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
 
_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3
 
_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get